# Accessing IP restricted URI from Azure function (powershell)

Tags: function, azure, azure-functions

I'd like to know given a Powershell function such as:

```
$url = "http://AnIPrestrictedURL"
[xml]$xml = (new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString($url)
```

with $url being an IP restricted url what are my options (if any) to be able to make this work? Is VPN an option or some other method? Would Express route (obv cost not being a factor) or point to site VPN work for this??

EDIT: To make this clearer? I have control of the IPRestrictedUrl server so in theory I could allow access to this via VPN / express route presumably without the IP restriction?? this is the point of the question?

Perhaps I should have said "how can I use an Azure Function with a service I do not want to be publicly accessible" If it matters the end service is SOLR

Comment: Aren't you able to whitelist Azure IPs in that service?

Comment: @Mikhail - Do you mean in the ""http://AnIPrestrictedURL" service? I have an on premise URL that I need the Azure function to be able to talk to but that on premis URL is IP restricted and the Azure function won't have a static IP presumably

Comment: Yes. Azure can provide you with Outbound IP addresses, see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43656397/1171619). I'm not exactly sure if they are fixed in stone or might change over time.

Comment: Thanks @Mikhail I did see that but assumed that they weren't fixed, I'd much rather not rely on that without documentation as the idea would be this would replace some fairly low level batch processes that are meant to keep going without much / any investigation long term.

Answer (score 4):

While the list of Outbound IPs is provided for Azure Web App (and is stable), the equivalent does not exist for Azure Function Apps. The reason is that they get scaled out very dynamically, and can end up running across many scale units, each with a different set of Outbound IPs.

So generally, you cannot make assumptions on Outbound IPs when using Azure Functions.

Comment: Thanks @David Ebbo that answers in terms of IP / being able to rely on it. Do you know re: express route / point to site VPN?

Comment: Not really expert on that part. Maybe ask new question focusing on that?

Comment: I thought that was the focus of or rather I tried that to be the focus of the question?

Comment: If you're willing to use a dedicated app service plan instead of the consumption plan, then you could try using hybrid connections. Basically you would run the hybrid connection manager on a server that has access to your SOLR server. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/biztalk-services/integration-hybrid-connection-overview

Comment: Thanks @PaulBatum I think that looks like what I want, but I can't see a documented reference to Azure functions - mark it as the answer and will mark it thanks :)